# How to set different individual Transition effects to Listitems in windows phone 8 app

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8

I'm having list,it contains only 10 items. I tried to set different transition effects to all individually for the 10 list item,but i failed to get that output.please help me.

Comment: what are the transition effects? post one effect (on a listitem) for example.

Comment: <toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>

        <toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
            <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
                <toolkit:RotateTransition Mode="In180Clockwise" />
            </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
            <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
                <toolkit:RotateTransition Mode="In180Counterclockwise" />
            </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
        </toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
    </toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>

Comment: using this in xaml instead of xaml i want to do programatically